# Locking a local coordinate

Tags: game-engine, coordinates

I'm using the BGE and I have an object that I defined as a "Rigid Body" in "Physics". I need to lock the X local coordinate but, if I lock it in "Lock translation", this lock the X global coordinate. How could I do to lock only X local?